# Regex using rebus in R splitting issue?

Tags: r, regex, string

I have the following string pattern:

Name_session_id:Owner:UUID BUT sometimes it can be just Name:Owner:UUID.

For example:

```
John_1:David:enfl43erl34r345
```

or

```
John:David:enfl43erl34r345
```

I want to use `stringr` and `rebus` to be able to build a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Name   Session   Owner   UUID
John   1         David   enfl43erl34r345
John   NA        David   enfl43erl34r345
```

Please advise how to do this, here is what I have done so far with the pattern:

```
capture(one_or_more(WRD)) %R% 
  optional("_") %R% 
  capture(optional(DGT)) %R% 
  ":" %R% 
  capture(one_or_more(WRD)) %R% 
  ":" %R% 
  capture(one_or_more(WRD))
```

Comment: That's because of the first `one_or_more(WRD)`, it matches `_`, too.

Comment: So what do you suggest? To replace _ to : and play from there? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You may start the expression with `capture(one_or_more(ALNUM))` to only capture 1+ digits or letters into Group 1.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm! Please turn to an answer.

Comment: See [my answe below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52493527/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if the strings are within a column, and I wan to split it to 4 columns I should use `separate(df, col, sep = pattern, into("name", "session", "owner", "uuid", convert = T)`?

Comment: If you use capturing, you probably need `tidyr::extract`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the first `one_or_more(WRD)`, it matches `_`, too, and the following `_` and `\d?` are not even tried since `\w+` grabs the whole chunk of letters, digits and underscores.

Replace the first `one_or_more(WRD)` with `one_or_more(ALNUM)` to only capture 1+ letters or digits into Group 1:

```
capture(one_or_more(ALNUM)) %R% 
  optional("_") %R% 
   capture(optional(DGT)) %R% 
    ":" %R% 
     capture(one_or_more(WRD)) %R% 
      ":" %R% 
       capture(one_or_more(WRD))
```

Or, make it lazy with `lazy(one_or_more(WRD))`:

```
capture(lazy(one_or_more(WRD))) %R% 
  optional("_") %R% 
   capture(optional(DGT)) %R% 
    ":" %R% 
     capture(one_or_more(WRD)) %R% 
      ":" %R% 
       capture(one_or_more(WRD))
```

However, I believe you should use

```
capture(one_or_more(ALNUM)) %R% 
  optional(
    group("_" %R% 
     capture(one_or_more(DGT)))) %R% 
      ":" %R% 
       capture(one_or_more(WRD)) %R% 
        ":" %R% 
         capture(one_or_more(WRD))
```

It will create a regex like [`([[:alnum:]]+)(?:_([\d]+))?:([\w]+):([\w]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/XCzzA4/1).  That is, instead of using `_` as an optional char followed with an optional `one_or_more(DGT)`, you can wrap these two subsequent patterns with an optional group while making the patterns obligatory inside it.

Answer (score 2):

Playing with some regex, you can rely solely on `stringr::str_extract()`:

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(
  Name = str_extract(data, "^[^:_]+"),
  Session = str_extract(data, "(?<=_).*?(?=:)"),
  Owner = str_extract(data, "(?<=:).*(?=:)"),
  UUID = str_extract(data, "[^:]*$"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

  Name Session Owner            UUID
1 John       1 David enfl43erl34r345
2 John    <NA> David enfl43erl34r345
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using `rebus`, but here is a no bullshit approach in base:

data:

```
df1 <-
data.frame(strings = c("John_1:David:enfl43erl34r345", "John:David:enfl43erl34r345"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

code:

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
    ans <- strsplit(x, "^[^:]+\\K_(?=\\d)", perl = T)
    ans <- lapply(ans, strsplit, ":")
    ans <- unlist(ans)
    if(length(ans) == 3) { ans <- append(ans, NA, 1) }
    return(ans)
}

result <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df1, 1, fun1)), stringsAsFactors = F)
names(result) = c("Name", "Session", "Owner", "UUID")
```

result:

```
#  Name Session Owner            UUID
#1 John       1 David enfl43erl34r345
#2 John    <NA> David enfl43erl34r345
```